# Call JAR file from angular 4 application

Tags: angular, jar

I am developing web application in Angular 4. In my login module, after successful login I need to decrypt cookie value using method defined in .jar file.

My development environment is WINDOWS and hosting environment is LINUX.

Can any one guide me how to call method of jar file in Angular 4 application ?

Thanks,
Pushkar

Answer (score 1):

First, I think the goal of doing crypto (decryption) in the browser is probably a red flag…there's very likely a better way. Check out [Java Web Tokens](https://jwt.io) as a start.

If you really want to call Java code in the browser, you *could* use a Java applet, but browser support is limited (and waning). The only other option that I'm aware of is a web application server to host your Java code. The Angular (UI) would call the method on your web service. You'll have to figure out authentication and authorization of the web service. This is a pretty big topic, out of the scope of this question & answer.

Comment: Thanks Barry for your comments.I understand your concern over decryption on client side. Yes as you said I am also looking for some kind of back end operation to decrypt the value. Thank you for your comments.